# Configuring varnish to write an apache error log with IP addresses

Tags: apache-2.2, ubuntu, varnish, fail2ban

I am in the process of installing fail2ban on a webserver which runs Varnish. Many on the 'jails' require access to the apache/php error logs.

One of the problems I have is that all of the refernces to IP addresses in the log files are 127.0.0.1.

I solved this problem regarding the access.log by running the following command:

```
varnishncsa -a -w /var/log/varnish/access.log -D -P /var/run/varnishncsa.pid
```

Is it possible to do something similar for the logs that appear in: /var/log/apache/*_error.log?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Add the following in to your `/etc/varnish/default.vcl`

```
sub vcl_recv {
  remove req.http.X-Forwarded-For;
  set req.http.X-Forwarded-For = client.ip;
}
```

Update your apache configuration to change your `CustomLog` to the following:

```
LogFormat "%{X-Forwarded-For}i %l %u %t \"%r\" %>s %b" varnishcombined
CustomLog /var/log/example.com-access_log varnishcombined
```

For more information, check this page: http://www.techinfobest.com/getting-real-client-ip-through-varnish/

Comment: This enables IP logging for the apache access logs. I already have this part working. I need the apache ERROR logs to record the IP address. Can the solution you provided be tweaked so it works with the error logs?

Comment: @Richelliot I don't believe so, unless you're running Apache 2.4 which has the [ErrorLogFormat](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/mod/core.html#errorlogformat) directive.